# Template not working on jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have a problem with jsf 1.2, in particular with the template loading.
My web.xml open index.xhtml.

(index.xhtml)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>H1 index</h1>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

(template.xhtml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<head>
<title>Titolo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />

    <ui:insert name="content" />

</body>
</html>
```

(header.xhtml)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:outputText value="This is the header 23456"/>

</ui:composition>
```

When I run my application I see only "H1 index". I don't see "This is the header 23456" and I don't see title. Why?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `<u:define name="header">` in your header.html too, just as you did in your index.html with `<u:define name="content">`. If you want to insert "anything else" into template without defining every section, just use `<u:insert />` in your template. This will insert every undefined block into your template.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I'm sorry, but it doesn't work. It seems that template.xhtml is not working, and so nothing xhtml work. index.xhtml works because it is in web.xml definition. Have you got other ideas?